# Changing Themes Only Applies Window Background Color

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

This is an extension to my previous answered question
 [How to Change Theme XAML with ComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43306907/how-to-change-theme-xaml-with-combobox)

---

I have a `ComboBox` that changes Themes between `ThemeBlue.xaml` and `ThemeRed.xaml`.

Here's the example project file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BycnCTAQ1U7gSU5kUUdaNzRIZDg

ThemeBlue.xaml: https://kopy.io/8HcDd
ThemeRed.xaml: https://kopy.io/iWWLC

**Blue Theme**

[image: Blue Theme]

**Red Theme**

Problem:
When you choose Red, only the Window Background color is changed, but not the `TextBox` or `Button`.

[image: Red Theme]

---

#### ComboBox Theme Select

**XAML**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboTheme" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxCustom}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="199,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" SelectionChanged="themeSelect_SelectionChanged">
    <System:String>Blue</System:String>
    <System:String>Red</System:String>
    <System:String>Purple</System:String>
</ComboBox>
```

**C#**

```
private void cboTheme_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string theme = cboTheme.SelectedItem.ToString();

    App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
    App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("Theme" + theme + ".xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) });

    // Save Theme for next launch
    Settings.Default["Theme"] = cboTheme.SelectedItem.ToString();
    Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

#### App.xaml

The theme file is loaded through `App.xaml` at startup

```
<Application x:Class="MultiTheme.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MultiTheme"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ThemeBlue.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

#### MainWindow.xaml

A `TextBox` with the Theme Style applied:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxCustom}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="93,43,0,0" Width="464" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DynamicResource` markup extension instead of `StaticResource` when you set the `Style` properties in `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Button x:Name="button" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonCustom}" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="304,171,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxCustom}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="78" Margin="28,77,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="351"/>
```

[What's the difference between StaticResource and DynamicResource in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200839/whats-the-difference-between-staticresource-and-dynamicresource-in-wpf)

Comment: I've applied it to my larger project and it is working well. Thanks for your help.